# How to make Chrome and/or Firefox play <audio> elements in Karma tests?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, karma-runner, html5-audio

I'm working on a library that can extract audio from HTML5 `<audio>` and `<video>` elements and send it to a remote server for speech-to-text processing. (e.g. automatic subtitles.) When I test manually, everything works as expected, but when karma runs my test, it always fails for `<audio>` elements.

For context, HTML5 [audio script processors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createScriptProcessor) immediately get a stream of audio as soon as they are connected to an `<audio>` element, but it's all 0's (no sound) until the element begins playing.

When my tests run in karma, it appears that the element never begins playing; I just get 0's even though I've called `.play()` on the element. Also, I don't hear any audio coming out of my speakers, which should happen at the same time.

(I get that audio during tests could be super-annoying and probably *should* be disabled by default, but is there a way to enable it for cases like mine?)

If you're interested in seeing the code, it's at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk but it's still a bit of a mess, and is currently configured to skip the tests that would fail. If necessary, I'll try and set up a stripped down example, but I'm hoping I won't need to.

I'm on OS X if it makes a difference. I haven't tried this on Windows or Linux yet.

Answer (score 2):

Found it, at least for firefox. `<audio>` elements apparently have stronger CORS rules than I realized! I was setting a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header on my file server, because I knew it was on a different port then where Karma was running my tests, but apparently that's not enough.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this *anywhere*, but I happened to notice a chrome Error about CORS and did a little more digging & experimentation. It seems that scriptProcessors for cross-domain `<audio>` elements need the the same `crossOrigin` attribute that `<img>` tags need to use their content in a `<canvas>`.

So, in the end, going from

```
  var audioElement = new Audio();
  audioElement.src = "http://localhost:9877/audio.wav";
```

to

```
  var audioElement = new Audio();
  audioElement.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  audioElement.src = "http://localhost:9877/audio.wav";
```

Solved the issue for me in firefox, and chrome works sometimes but seems to have some other issues (perhaps related to load time?).

I believe the second issue in chrome is that I was calling `.play()` right away and then ending my test when it emitted an `ended` event.. but that event seems to also fire when the buffer runs empty, which I think is a bug. I changed it to wait on the `canplaythrough` event before calling `.play()` and it seems to be reliably passing the test now.

Answer (score 0):

Some browser implementations will block attempts to automatically play `<audio>` elements unless a user interaction has occurred (for obvious reasons).

There are several suggestions in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206631/html5-audio-cant-play-through-javascript-unless-triggered-manually-once), but they are all attempting to circumvent a designed feature and would probably not be very reliable across multiple browsers / devices.

Depending on your setup and which browsers you are targeting, you might need to factor in a *'click to start'* button in your test.