# JavaScript audio.play() error

Tags: javascript, audio

my code stopped working today (it worked before).

Here is my code:

```
playMe = new Audio(link);
playMe.play();
```

Here is the error I get in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

It is really the `audio.play();` that doesn't work because if I only keep the first line I don't get an error (but obviously is dos't play).

I'm using chrome 52.0.2743.82 m (64-bit)

Thanks.

Comment: well... it started to work again... i didn't do anything...

Comment: Amm... it started to give me the error again, I didn't change the code and there was not any chore updates...

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue, I'm running into the exact same problem.

Comment: It might be a problem with Chrome 50+. Have a look at this: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/28812647/4465386](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28812647/4465386)

Comment: I'm seeing this on Safari 11

Answer (score 1):

Before you play audio, window must be focused. For this case you can use:

```
playMe = new Audio(link);
window.focus();
playMe.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

The below answer is for video. The same you can use for audio as well.

```
 var playPromise = document.querySelector('video').play();
  // In browsers that don’t yet support this functionality,
 // playPromise won’t be defined.
 if (playPromise !== undefined) {
  playPromise.then(function() {
 // Automatic playback started!
 }).catch(function(error) {
  // Automatic playback failed.
 // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback.
});
}
```

Comment: Working on audio, tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem as you.
I tried playing a `<audio>` html element and it worked!
So I thought that maybe...
The only thing you should do is to append `playMe` to body...

```js
var play_me = new Audio("music.mp3");
document.body.appendChild(play_me);
play_me.play();
```

But don't worry the `play_me` isn't visible.