# How can I allow my webview to play an audio from webserver?

Tags: javascript, android-studio, webview, webserver

I'm creating a webserver on RPI3 that will display the status of the baby(Lying Down, Sitting, Out of the Crib). It will also play a sound notification once the status is "Out of the Crib".

The javasript of my webserver is this:

```
function notif() {

var pos = $('.status').text();
var audio = new Audio('alarm.mp3');

if(pos == "Out of the crib") {
audio.play();
}
```

This code is working fine when I access my webserver in different laptop. But when I view my webserver in android webview it does not play the sound, but in different laptop it's working.

Should I do something on my java file in android studio or android webview does not support this kind of thing?

But I tried to add button in my webserver that will play the sound once it's click. And I open it again in my webview and it's working I dont know what to do. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say but this is a feature not a bug.
This is done on purpose to prevent developers from forcing the user to hear/see things without user interaction.

The only thing that you are allowed is to play a **muted** video without user interaction.

You can override this but only on your device.
See [this question and the several answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12206631/1571605) that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Comment: Do not post code-only answers. While your solution may work, answers should also provide some explanation of why the code will resolve the issue raised in the question.