# The AudioContext was not allowed to start. AngularJS Recorder Chrome 71

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-audio

I've been using AngularAudioRecorder (AngularJS) for the last 4 years and with the last Chrome update I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.
> init @ angular-audio-recorder.js: 861
> ```

Code:

```
getPermission: function () {
      navigator.getUserMedia({
        "audio": true
      }, html5HandlerConfig.gotStream, html5HandlerConfig.failStream);
    },
    init: function () {
      service.isHtml5 = true;
      var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      if (AudioContext && !html5AudioProps.audioContext) {
        html5AudioProps.audioContext = new AudioContext();
      }

      if (localStorage.getItem("permission") !== null) {
        //to get permission from browser cache for returning user
        html5HandlerConfig.getPermission();
      }
    }
  };
```

Please find the full code here:   [Angular Audio Recorder](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/logbon72/angular-recorder/master/dist/angular-audio-recorder.js)

Thank you for any help you can offer

Comment: Have you seen this? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio

Comment: yes, I've tried several times to implement this and failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved the problem**. Finally resumed the paused **AudioContext** with:

```
html5AudioProps.audioContext.resume().then(() => {
     var audioContext = html5AudioProps.audioContext;
})
```

Inside the function that starts the recording.

Answer (score 1):

do it when user press any key or touch any button

`if(audio_context.state !== 'running') {
    audio_context.resume();
 }`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is nothing which only applies to Angular; it's much more general, and has to do with the fact that modern browsers have disabled auto-playing sounds (until user has interacted 'enough') so that you're not annoyed by sounds of some web page which you just opened.

see this old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206631/html5-audio-cant-play-through-javascript-unless-triggered-manually-once).

I was getting the exact same 'not allowed to start' message, and I'm not using Angular; I was just trying to have JavaScript play a sound (programmatically) before 'enough' user interaction. What I did to fix it was to take care that `... = new AudioContext()` is executed only after the user has pressed a button or interacted with a (native) slider. The accepted answer to above old question suggests essentially the same strategy.

Good to see that you already solved the problem. Probably (caution: not tested) an alternative solution would be to just delay the loading and/or initialization of the recorder code until the user has pressed some button or so.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  context.close();
}, timenotification);
```