Sound doesn't play until interacting with the page
I'm trying to add a sound effect to my page when the user scrolls with his mouse wheel.
When the page is loaded up and the user scrolls, the listener works as expected but the sound isn't being played.
Only when I interact with the page (for example by clicking with my mouse) and then scroll then I can hear the scrolling sound effect.
I tried playing the sound through my JS script one time with volume to 0 but didn't solve the problem.
Even manually adding a document.click() at the start of the script didn't help.
JS code:
click.preload = 'auto';

var sc = new Audio("/SND/scroll.wav");
sc.preload = 'auto';

// Tried to autoplay the sound one time
sc.volume = 0.0;
sc.play();
sc.volume = 1.0;
sc.pause();
sc.currentTime = 0;

function playClick(evt){
    if(evt.target.nodeName == "input" ||
       evt.target.id == "arrw_l" ||
       evt.target.id == "arrw_r"
    ){
        click.currentTime = 0; click.play();
    }
}

function playScroll(evt){
    sc.currentTime = 0; sc.play();
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.addEventListener('wheel', playScroll);
    document.addEventListener('click', playClick);
}


This is done by most browsers to prevent auto-playing audio, as that used to be regularly abused and is generally not good UX. There's no way to avoid this, but for various peoples work arounds, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206631/html5-audio-cant-play-through-javascript-unless-triggered-manually-once

This is impossible. More details can be found in the following link:
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/can-we-play-sound-of-a-video-without-user-interaction/67865/2
